# How to connect with SecureAS400 using SSL/SSH working example

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jtopen

I work with several IBM i systems. One of them needs me to set an SSH connection before opening an 5250 session. I use the command: ssh -i Keys_rsa L 50023:localhost:23 USER@HOST and after open a 5250 session pointing to IP 127.0.0.1 and it works... But i have a java program that gets some data from the server that cant connect. I need an example of connecting and setting ports. I use JTOpen/JT400 **AS400** object but i think i need to move to a **SecureAS400** object... Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont have any code... I cant figure out how to do this... In a normal situation i use putty or a command line to create the connection and tinnels and the just execute an ACS 5250 session... I want to do the same with Java but the application does not seam to be able to use the connection and tunnels i created... In this case i cant find any info on how to do this... Sorry... Thanks....